# AWS CLI and S3 browsers not working after enabling Force_MFA

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cli

I have added force_mfa policy and after that IAM users couldn't use AWS CLI and S3 browser. Getting **You are not authorized to perform this operation** error. Please check below link for force_mfa policy.

Force_MFA policy : https://s3.amazonaws.com/awsiammedia/public/sample/DelegateManagementofMFA/DelegateManagementofMFA_policydocument_060115.txt

Can somebody suggest solution for this.

Comment: Do NOT use this policy.  It allows an attacker to bypass your MFA requirement, as described in https://duo.com/blog/potential-gaps-in-suggested-amazon-web-services-security-policies-for-mfa

Answer (score 0):

Configure AWS CLI to use MFA as well.

Add an IAM role (e.g. called poweruser). Edit your profile in ~/.aws/config

```
[profile poweruser]
role_arn = arn:aws:iam::111111111111:role/PowerUser
source_profile = default
mfa_serial = arn:aws:iam::111111111111:mfa/johndoe
```

Source: https://cloudonaut.io/improve-aws-security-protect-your-keys-with-ease/

Comment: Is there any way I can configure API calls without MFA. I need MFA only for console login.

Comment: IAM policies apply wether you are using the Management Console, the CLI or any other possibility to access the AWS API. I couldn't find a way to exclude the CLI from MFA via an IAM policy. A solution could be to use different IAM users to login via Management Console and for the use with the CLI.